# Grouping pandas data frame with aggregation function returning more than 1 row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose that I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   grp  x  y    z
a    1  6  4  3.0
b    2  5  5  4.0
c    1  4  6  5.0
d    2  3  7  6.0
e    1  2  8  7.0
f    2  1  9  NaN
```

I want to group by the `grp` column and select the first two rows from each group. So here's what I expect:

```
   grp  x  y    z
a    1  6  4  3.0
c    1  4  6  5.0
b    2  5  5  4.0
d    2  3  7  6.0
```

How do I do that with pandas?

Comment: ``df.groupby('grp').head(2)``

Comment: That's great and solves this particular problem! More generally, how would I solve a similar situation with a custom function that takes a DataFrame and returns a DataFrame?

Comment: As an example, let's say I have a function that returns the top and bottom rows of a DataFrame. How do I incorporate that function in the groupby operation?

Comment: the `nth` function covers that. share an example data input with expected data output, so I am sure we are on the same page regarding your question

Comment: `df.groupby('grp').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0,-1]])`? The point is that you can just process as usual, pandas will handle the concatenation of the output dataframe.

Comment: Ok. Great answers.  Maybe I should ask for a more complex scenario :-) Let's say I want to group by 'grp' again but choose only rows where the value of x is greater than the value of y.  So in this example, only row 'a' would be returned.

Comment: this new scenario does not require `groupby`, you can filter on the whole dataframe. please edit your question if you want to specify/change your problem.

Comment: That's fair. My bad. I will keep the same spirit of this question for now, and let's go with a different example. What if I want to group by 'grp' and within each group I want to select *all* rows and an *additional* row having the sum of the values from each column?